# Sidemenu access ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

Controller.js:

```
.controller('ParametresCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams','$state','cgtdata','$ionicPopup',

 function($scope,$stateParams,$state,cgtdata,$ionicPopup) {
  document.getElementById('test').style.color='red';
```

menu.html:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">


      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Tiime-ae</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <!--<ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
          Login
        </ion-item>-->
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/home">
          Home
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/registre">
          registre
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/documents">
          Documents
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/facturer">
          Facturer
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/parametres">
          Paramètres
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

parametres.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Parametres">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <div class="h1 title">Header Buttons</div>
  <button id="test" class="button button-clear button-positive">Edit</button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content>

    <h2>Mon Compte</h2>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item">
        <p class="param-right">{{email}}</p><p>Email :</p>
        </li>
        <li class="item" ng-click="changepass()">


        <div class="chevron-mdp ion-chevron-right" data-pack="default" data-tags="arrow,right"></div>
        <p>Modifier mon mot de passe : </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Activité</h2>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item">
          <ion-toggle  ng-repeat="item in settingsList"
                       ng-model="item.checked"
                       ng-checked="item.checked">
              {{ item.text }}
            </ion-toggle>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <h2 id="edit">Mon entreprise</h2>
    <ul class="list">
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
              Période de déclaration
            </div>
            <select>
              <option>Mensuelle</option>
              <option>Trimestrielle</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>


        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
              Bénéficiaire ACCRE
            </div>
            <select>
              <option>Oui</option>
              <option>Non</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>




        <li class="item">
          <input ng-change="firstchange()" ng-model="nam" class="param-right"></input><p>Prénom</p>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <p class="param-right">{{lastname}}</p><p>Nom</p>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <p class="param-right">{{commercial}}</p><p>Nom Commercial</p>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <p class="param-right">{{siret}}</p><p>Siret</p>

        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <p class="param-right">{{creation}}</p><p>Date de création</p>

        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <p class="param-right">{{addresse}}</p><p>Addresse</p>

        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <p class="param-right">{{cp}}</p><p>Code postal</p>

        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <p class="param-right">{{city}}</p><p>Ville</p>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
        <p class="param-right">{{country}}</p><p>Pays</p>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
        <p class="param-right">{{phone}}</p><p>Téléphone</p>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <p>Ville d'imatriculation au RCS :</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Factures</h2>
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
              Délai de réglement
            </div>
            <select>
              <option>A la réception</option>
              <option>une semaine</option>
              <option>15 jours</option>
              <option>3 semaines</option>
              <option>30 jours</option>
              <option>40 jours</option>
              <option>45 jours</option>
              <option>60 jours</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>

        <li class="item" ng-click="entete()">
          <div class="chevron-mdp ion-chevron-right" data-pack="default" data-tags="arrow,right"></div>
        <p>En tête</p>
        </li>
        <li class="item" ng-click="mentions()">
          <div class="chevron-mdp ion-chevron-right" data-pack="default" data-tags="arrow,right"></div>
          <p>Mentions légales</p>

        </li>
        <li class="item" ng-click="piedpage()">
          <div class="chevron-mdp ion-chevron-right" data-pack="default" data-tags="arrow,right"></div>
        <p>Pied de page</p>


        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="button-bar bar-assertive">
      <a class="button activated" ng-click="showConfirm()">Deconnexion</a>
    </div>



  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I m new in angular, here is my issue :
My controller.js is link to my parametres.html
and i have the following error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Because i would like to use css on my button "edit" from my controller. So i put my button into parametres.html.

```
<ion-view view-title="Parametres">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <div class="h1 title">Header Buttons</div>
  <button id="test" class="button button-clear button-positive">Edit</button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content>
```

Because what i want to do is : with ng-change when i change something in parametres.html like a value, my button "edit" appear.
Someone knows how i can access to css property of a my button "edit" from controller which is not in ion-content ?

Answer (score 0):

ok i just use this :

```
  <button ng-style="displayed" class="button button-clear button-positive">Edit</button>
```

and in my controller : `$scope.displayed = {'color':'red'};`

i didn t know that ng-class existed !

And it works !